# Show size in layer navigation if product available in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to show size on layered navigation if associated product is in-stock. 
For example

I have added 3 shirt having size **XL , XXL , L**.

There is product filter by size in left(layer navigation) showing **XS , M , XL , XXL , L**(all size which I do not want. I want it should show size if product is available ).

Any idea?

Comment: found answer? @Taukli Ali

Answer (score 0):

Select "**Filterable (with results)**" in **Use In Layered Navigation** under **Manage Attributes**

[image]

That's All. I hope, it would help you